# vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer not copying the full imageExtent

Tags: vulkan

I have an issue with the Vulkan `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` function. According to the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkBufferImageCopy) the `imageExtent` member of the `VkBufferImageCopy` passed to this function...

> ...is the size in **texels** of the image to copy in width, height and depth.

However, when attempting to copy **the color aspect of an uncompressed `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_*`** 2D image, only 1/4 of the image is read. If I multiply the fields of `imageExtent` by 4 the whole image is read. 
On the other hand, if I change the image format to e.g. `VK_FORMAT_R32G32_*`, I can detect that half the image is read. It seems to me that unless I use `VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_*` for the color aspect of the image the function will misbehave.

Did I miss something in the specs?

Thanks for any hints.

P.S.: I will try to get AMD involved in case this is a driver issue. I'm currently awaiting confirmation/whitelisting in order to access their forums. I have had an account since 2009 but I'm still considered a newcomer apparently.

Edit: BTW, there are no errors/warnings/performance warnings from the LunarG Vulkan SDK validation layers.

Comment: Are you sure the value you stored in your buffer are really in R8G8B8A8 and not in r32g32b32a32?

Are you using the good vkImageSubrsourcesLayers? Are you setting bufferRowLength / offsets properly?

If you have a 128 * 128 images. Make sure your buffer size is 128 * 128 * 4 and not 128 * 128 * 32.

If you want to copy image with format conversion, filtering ou arbitrary scaling (mipmap?), use vkCmdBlitImage instead

Comment: Please provide the actual code involved (including the code creating the images). As well as whatever data is needed.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier I think you might have nailed it. The source image is being properly copied as requested (4x8 bits). However, the target buffer is being checked through a texel buffer as 4x32bit so my data might be inadvertently 'packed' in the process. That would explain some more issues I'm having. I need to double check this.

Comment: @NicolBolas Unfortunately, Vulkan isn't really friendly to the "minimum example" approach. I've tried doing that for the past week and failed miserably.

Comment: Happy To help To solve your problem 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Antoine's comment (especially to his very first question) I managed to solve the issue. The copy command was correctly copying all of the 4x8bit values from the source image to the (much larger) target buffer. However the target buffer was subsequently processed by fragment shaders through a `VkBufferView` with a mismatching 4x32bit format. As such the copy command was seemingly updating only 1/4th of the target buffer by fitting 4 source texels into 1 target texel.

Fun times.